# Size of Objects in Java Heap w/ Regards to Methods

Tags: java, methods, heap-memory, classloader

I know about primitives and objects living on the heap, but how does the number of methods effect heap size of the object?

For example:

```
public class A {
    int x;
    public getX() { return x; }
}

public class B {
    int x;

    public getX() { return x; }
    public getXString() { return String.valueOf(x); }
    public doMoreInterestingStuff() { return x * 42; }
    //etc
}
```

When instantiated, both objects live on the heap, both have memory allocated to their primitive `x`, but is B allocated more heap space due to having more method signatures?  Or are those ONLY on the permGen space?  In this example its trivial, but when there are 100,000+ of these objects in memory at any given time I imagine it could add up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does the number of methods effect heap size of the object?

It doesn't. It has no impact on the per-object size, and indeed it would have no need to - it's not like each object of that type has different methods.

Obviously the extra methods take up memory "somewhere" (associated with the class, basically) but it's not on a per *object* basis.

Comment: +1 Methods are stored in the PermGen, so the number of methods you use has no impact on the heap.

Comment: This was my initial suspicion and best guess based on how I know the permGen worked, thank you for confirming it Jon.  I had a silly notion that maybe the object held a reference back to the permGen for each method associated with it.

Comment: Nope, the reference is only to the class as a whole.